# How to implement Angular Route Animations?

Tags: angular, angular-animations

I'm trying to implement angular route animations. I've followed the documentation as well as referred to this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7JA90VI9fAI. But I cannot get the animations working. Here is the code so far: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-animations-not-working

#### animations.ts

```
import { trigger, transition, animate, style, query } from '@angular/animations';

export const fader =
  trigger('routeAnimations', [
    transition('* <=> *', [
      query(':enter, :leave', [
        style({
          position: 'absolute',
          left: 0,
          width: '100%',
          opacity: 0,
          transform: 'scale(0) translateY(100%)'
        })
      ], { optional: true }),
      query(':enter', [
        animate('600ms ease', style({
          opacity: 1, transform: 'scale(1) translateY(0)'
        })),
      ], { optional: true })
    ])
  ]);
```

#### app.component.html

```
<a [routerLink]="['home']">Home</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a [routerLink]="['hello']">Hello</a>
<div class="route-content" [@routeAnimations]="prepareRoute(outlet)">
  <router-outlet #outlet="outlet"></router-outlet>
</div>
```

#### app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { fader } from './animations';
import { RouterOutlet } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ],
  animations: [
    fader
  ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
  prepareRoute(outlet: RouterOutlet) {
    return outlet && outlet.activatedRouteData && outlet.activatedRouteData['animation'];
  }
}
```

#### styles.css

```
.route-content {
  position: relative;
}
```

Can someone please help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks for post the question. Can you please update your question with source code examples of what you've tried so far. Having a link to stackblitz is very helpful, but people won't bother reviewing your code on an external site. You'll get better engagement with a better details.

Comment: plz add this is route { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent,data: {animation: 'HomePage'} },

Comment: Thanks @Reactgular. I've added the code snippet here

Comment: Thanks a lot, @JadavPalak. It's working for me now. I've been searching for the solution for 2-3 hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add data: {animation: 'HomePage'} in your routes

```
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent, data: {animation: 'HomePage'} },
```

accoding to https://angular.io/guide/route-animations